# Which one is better approach window.parent.location.href or window.top.location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working in a project where I have to redirect on Error Page in a particular scenario. For that I have created Error.aspx page. Right now I am using 
window.top.location.href = "../Error.aspx" and it generate http://localhost/app_web/Error.aspx
and its working fine except once (which shows Message http://xyz/ErrorPage.aspx' does not exist. ). So can anyone suggest which is the better option for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`top` is "better than" `parent` if your intent is to framebust your page into the top level, because your page may be inside a frame that is itself inside a frame.

As for your relative path problem, you may want to try:

```
var local = location.pathname.split("/");
local.pop(); // remove the filename
local.pop(); // remove the containing directory
local.push("Error.aspx");
local = location.protocol+"//"+location.hostname+"/"+local.join("/");
top.location.href = local;
```

Answer (score 10):

`window.parent` refers to the parent window of the current window. That parent *may* have it's own parent, which has its own parent etc.

`window.top` refers to this top most window; e.g. `window.parent.parent.parent[...]`;

In this circumstance however, you probably only want to redirect the current window, e.g;

```
window.location.href = "../Error.aspx";
```

For more info, see the documentation on [`window.parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.parent), [`window.top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.top) and [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location).

Comment: To summarize, the answer to the question depends upon which window the OP wants the error URL to go into, one parent up in the frame hierarchy (`window.parent`)?  The top-most frame (`window.top`)?  Or the current window (`window.location`).  If there are no frames, all three of these will be the same.  If there is only one level of frame, then `window.top` and `window.parent` are the same.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on what you are trying to do.

1. #### `window.parent.location`

   is used to change the location of the parent window.
2. #### `window.top.location`

   - It is a property of the object 'window'.
   - It returns the location of the topmost window in the window hierarchy.
   - If a window has no parent, top is a reference to itself (window === window.top)