# Why I can't redirect to another URL when I close a modal dialog in SharePoint?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

very new in SharePoint and I have the following problem implementing a specific modal dialog behavior in SharePoint 2013.

I have the following situation. In a webpart I am opening another webpart into a modal dialog (and this is not a problem). Then, when the modal dialog is closed, I have to refresh the parent page (not the dialog that is closed) into another webpart. I am trying to implement this behavior via JavaScript, in this way:

```
string javascript = "function openEdit(link) {"         +
                        "var options = {"               +
                                        "url: link,"    +
                                        "dialogReturnValueCallback: Callback"   + 
                                       "};"             +
                        "SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);"  +
                     "}"                                +
                     "function Callback(dialogResult, ret)  {"          +
                        "alert('TEST');"                +
                        "window.frameElement.commitPopup();"            +
                        //"window.location.replace(\"" + linkRed + "\");" +
                        "window.parent.location.herf = 'http://www.google.com'" +

                     "}"                                +
                     "openEdit(\"" + linkPrint + "\");";

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), "CallJS", javascript, true);
```

As you can see, in my parent webpart I am using the **openEdit()** JS function to open the link (represented by the value of the **linkPrint** string variable (it works).

I am also declaring **callback** function that is called when my modal dialog is closed. It correctly enter into this **Callback()** function (I see it because I put the alert()) but then I expected to be redirected to google.com (or to the URL on another webpart changing this value) but it is not working. It is redirecting and refreshing the parent page from where I opened my modal dialog window.

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: what the commitPopup do . may be yu should try an alert after that too . and may look into this ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889459/which-one-is-better-approach-window-parent-location-href-or-window-top-location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the code as below. Note: In you code replace "**herf**" with "**href**" and use **window.location.href** to redirect other page.

```
var linkPrint = "http://sp2013/sites/team/Lists/Test/EditForm.aspx?ID=1";
string javascript = "function openEdit(link) {" +
            "var options = {" +
                            "url: link," +
                            "dialogReturnValueCallback: Callback" +
                           "};" +
            "SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);" +
         "}" +
         "function Callback(dialogResult, ret)  {" +
            "alert('TEST');" +
            "window.location.href= 'http://www.google.com';" +
         "}" +
         "openEdit(\"" + linkPrint + "\");";

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), "CallJS", javascript, true);
```